# AMP: The tag 'amp-social-share' may not appear as a descendant of tag 'amp-sidebar'. Why?

Tags: amp-html

AMP validator shows me the following error:

> The tag 'amp-social-share' may not appear as a descendant of tag 'amp-sidebar'.

Honestly I do not understand a reason for such restriction. For example I want to show narrow sidebar on right when user clicks on the "share" icon; and the sidebar should have several amp-social-share items.

Why I can't do it?

**UPDATE**

AMP project team decided to remove this restriction. Details here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4273

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in this [documentation](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-sidebar/) that the `amp-sidebar` **may not contain any AMP Elements except for `amp-accordion`, `amp-img` and `amp-fit-text`**. So that is the reason you get this error because you put [`amp-social-share`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-social-share.html) under the amp-sidebar.

Also take note that there can be only one `amp-sidebar` in an AMP document. The `amp-sidebar` should be a direct child of the `<body>`. It must have a layout of no display.

Comment: Haha @KENdi Honestly it was a question for AMP project team. And they found my request valuable and decided to remove such restriction. Details here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4273